# Unable to start pod under kubernetes namespace

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a namespace on my physical K8 cluster.
Now I'm trying to spin-up resources with the help of *dep.yaml and namespace mentioned in the file.
Also created secrets under the same namespace.
But Status showing 'ContainerCreating'.

**application-dep.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-name
  namespace: namespace-service 
  labels:
    module: testmodule
...
```

Note: It's working in the default namespace.

Comment: If you do `kubectl describe pod <podname>` do you see any Events in the bottom?

Comment: Yes, Seems some MountVolume.SetUp failed. Let me fix it out. Thanks for your comments. I'm a beginner ...

Comment: So it was `MountVolume` setup issue or its something different? If you still have issue please provide whole Deployment YAML and error you are receiving. If you are creating PV manually please also provide this YAML.

Answer (score 0):

If a Pod is stuck in state `ContainerCreating`, it may be good to check the Events with `kubectl describe pod` and check the Events in the bottom.

There is usually an Event that explain why the Pod fails to reach state `Running`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the rest of the deployment file?
If you are currently running a service (assuming that it exposes a specific NodePort) in the default namespace, you cannot expose the same port again on a different namespace.

Also, as mentioned, you can always get more information using the "describe" command -

```
kubectl describe <resource> (can be a pod, deployment, service, etc)
```